# mobaxterm - Disconnected: No supported authentication methods available (server sent: publickey)

Tags: mobaxterm

I am using mobaxterm to connect to my google cloud compute but received the error "Disconnected: No supported authentication methods available (server sent: publickey)". How do i fix this ?